# Looking for a VoIP service provider

Tags: web-services, api, service, voip, telephony

I am looking for a VoIP service my application can use to call landlines and mobile phones.

What I need:

- I would generate an audio file and send it to the service. The service would then place the call and play the audio file.

Other features that would be a plus:

- TTS (I send text and the service converts it to audio for me)
- Ability to receive DTMF responses

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: I figure it is just as programming related as asking about a tool, component, or library.

Comment: This should be moved to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12932/telephony?referrer=s2GigkBNnqYlaRLwFFF1-A2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/). It is amazingly easy to use and does all that you want: [play](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api_reference/TwiML/play) audio files, [say](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api_reference/TwiML/say) text, and [gather](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api_reference/TwiML/gather) DTMF input. They've even got some speech to text transcription now.

Comment: +1 for Twilio - great flexible API.

Comment: I will definitely give Twilio a look.

Answer (score 1):

After quite a bit of digging I am going to give [CallFire](http://www.callfire.com/) a try.

It looks very promising.

Comment: How was your experience with CallFire?

Comment: The project has been delayed, so I haven't gotten a chance to try them out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try City Watch by Avtex.  It does all those things.

-Barnzy

Answer (score 0):

For calling and playing audio files you could have a look at the [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org) server. Altough this is not an external service which I think you're looking for, it could be used to connect to a VoIP-provider and play the file.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a service. Basically my customers would create their own account with the service that my application uses.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Axvoice](http://www.axvoice.com/), it's a low cost home phone service and you can surely integrate it with your application.

You can contact their live chat support for detailed info.